# FlexSlider for TYPO3 6 showing jQuery issues

Tags: jquery, typo3, flexslider

I'm using FlexSlider for my TYPO3 website. My website `Home` page uses jQuery and I'm linking like this

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="fileadmin/templates/js/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="slider">
     {slider}
  </div>
</body>
```

The problem is, if I give the link to `jquery-1.8.3.min.js` in the head then my Slider does not work. But If I remove it, it works. And I can't remove it, for other animation reasons.

So far I did this, in flexslider/Configuration/TypoScript/constansts.txt

I changed `settings.lib.jQuery to fileadmin/templates/js/jquery-1.8.3.min.js`

It still won't work.

So basically what I want to do is to change the jQuery source path to the jQuery file present in my fileadmin

Answer (score 1):

I don't like to have every extension include their own external libs, so I can recommend to just define the version you want and remove the extension include setting.

```
page.includeJS {
    jquery = //ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js
    jquery.external = 1
    jquery.forceOnTop = 1
}
plugin.tx_flexslider.settings.lib.jQuery >
```

All the code is in the `setup` part (not in `constants`) of my root page. This worked well on the sites we built recently.

Do you get an error on your site in the js console right now (then please post it) or does "It still won't work." just mean a blank page?